# Google Maps gives error in IE when loading via https

Tags: internet-explorer, google-maps, iframe

I'm trying to load a map via https into an iframe. In Firefox it works fine(and so does in IE when not using https), but in IE it gives the following error:

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
>   Timestamp: Wed, 14 Sep 2011 10:29:24 UTC
>
> Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
>   Line: 2449
>   Char: 9
>   Code: 0
>   URI: https://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/365b/maps2/%7Bmain,mod_util,mod_act,mod_actbr,mod_adf,mod_appiw,mod_dir,mod_hover,mod_mssvt,mod_poly,mod_qdt,mod_rst%7D.js

Here is my code:

```
<iframe width="600" height="500" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=dhl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;z=12&amp;output=embed#urlParam#"></iframe>
```

Does anyone have a fix for this?